# How to get guest customer info using bigcommerce api?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am able to get customers info if they have signed up but cannot get customer info if a new customer used the "guest" method during checkout. Looks as if the json record doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are checking the customers endpoint, that's correct. A customer record only exists for someone that has signed up with an account.

If you check the orders endpoint, you can get the details they checked out with as a guest. This is limited to the orders context only and the only place it is stored.